# Resetting results when year changes

Tags: mysql

**What I have:**

Scenario 1:

```
SELECT `agent_id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total_users
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`create_at`, '%m-%d-%Y') <= '01-01-2016'
GROUP BY `agent_id`
```

Result:

```
agent_id  |  total_users
------------------------
foo       |  0
bar       |  0
```

Scenario 2:

```
SELECT `agent_id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total_users
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`create_at`, '%m-%d-%Y') <= '12-31-2015'
GROUP BY `agent_id`
```

Result:

```
agent_id  |  total_users
------------------------
foo       |  532
bar       |  435
```

**The problem**

The `total_users` column for the date `01-01-2016` is always 0. But when I change the value from `01-01-2016` to `12-31-2015`, the value is different, it returns many users. It looks like that the data messes up when the year changes.

Comment: you should provide example data

Comment: what is the datatype of create_at ? in which date format it is save ?

Comment: @VipinJain it's an int, to store unix timestamp. I just converted it into date string using the from_unixtime(). I know that's a bad practice, but I'm not the one who designed this messy database.

Comment: isn't it should be mm-dd-yyyy ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above didn't work.

I don't know why but, this solution instead seemed to work:

instead of using

`WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(create_at, '%m-%d-%Y') <= '01-01-2016'`

I just omitted the second parameter of the function and reformatted the date to `Y-m-d`

So my where clause now looks like this

`WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(create_at) <= '2016-01-01'`

Weirdly it worked. Anyways, thanks for those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

In you example:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(`create_at`, '%m-%d-%Y') <= '01-01-2016'
```

It is not compared as DATE, but as string. That is why `01...` gives 0 while `12...` gives many rows. Because `12` is bigger than `01` as a string.

Therefore, to make it right, you can covert both to a DATE format:

```
SELECT `agent_id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total_users
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`create_at`) <= STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%m-%d-%Y');
GROUP BY `agent_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use `STR_TO_DATE` to a date string while comparing with another date it is considered to be string comparison.

Try the following query please :

```
SELECT `agent_id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total_users
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`create_at`, '%m-%d-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%m-%d-%Y')
GROUP BY `agent_id`;
```

**Check this too:**

`SELECT '01-01-2016' > '12-31-2015';`

**Result:** `0` `i.e.` `FALSE`. [ Because it's string comparison not date comparison.]

Now look at this:

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%m-%d-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('12-31-2015','%m-%d-%Y')`

**Result:** `1` `i.e.` `TRUE`.[ Because it's a date comparison now.]

Answer (score 0):

This is solution, convert your comparision date to unix time stamp and check with create_at

```
SELECT `agent_id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total_users
FROM `users`
WHERE `create_at` <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('01-01-2016')
GROUP BY `agent_id`
```

and

```
SELECT `agent_id`, COUNT(`id`) AS total_users
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`create_at`, '%m-%d-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%m-%d-%Y')
GROUP BY `agent_id`;
```

in second query there is two function call `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `STR_TO_DATE()` but in first query there is only one function call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. which solution is suitable you can use

Hope this will work for you